# Is there an alternative method to to stream() for ArrayLists in Java?

Tags: java, arrays

As I was looking for a way to print out Arrays nicely one by one, I found the `Arrays.stream(array)` method, which prints out an array exactly how I want.

But the problem is, that I have an dynamic array and that method mentioned above does not work. So is there any similar methods for ArrayLists?

```
String line;
BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(list));
List<String> lines = new ArrayList<>();

while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
    lines.add(line);
}

bufferedReader.close();

Arrays.stream(lines).forEach(System.out::println);
```

The last line is the line, which prints out arrays how I want, but no dynamic arrays. I am also aware of the alternative to add an `System.out.println(line)` in the `while` body.

Comment: an dynamic array ... you mean ArrayList? What's exactly the issue, you change the arraylist while you stream it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `ArrayList` you're streaming already has a `stream()` method:

```
lines.stream().forEach(System.out::println);
```

`Arrays.stream()` is for actual arrays, as in `String[]`, `int[]`, `MyObject[]` etc. `ArrayList` on the other hand is a `Collection` and collections have a `stream` method.

Answer (score 1):

Starting with the `Collection` level interface, you have `.stream()` method. However, in your case, you just use `.forEach()`. Every class implementing `Iterable` has this method.

```
List<String> myList = new ArrayList<>();
myList.add("one");
myList.add("two");
myList.add("three");

// You can just use .forEach() on any class implementing Iterable interface
myList.forEach(System.out::println);

// Or when .stream() is needed
myList.stream()
    .map(a -> "digit: " + a)
    .forEach(System.out::println);
```